# Batch training in Keras LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm, loss

If I use a `batch_size` of 32 in an `LSTM` made with `Keras`, is the loss function applied to each sequence and then averaged, or is it applied directly to all sequences without taking each sequence into account?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a batch_size of one would imply updating the weights after a sequence, a batch size of 32 would mean updating the weights after those 32 sequences.

So the weights are updated only after this chunk of 32 sequences, with the loss as average on all of those, since otherwise if the loss would be updated to each one in itself, it would actually represent the plain SGD with batch_size = 1.

Comment: Thanks. So, loss is computed for each sequence, averaged and backpropagated?

Comment: Yes. Even in Keras when you see the progress of the when the loss is modified it is modified only after this batch_size and accordingly the weights are updated as such, average of error is backpropagated.